# powershell + sql server provider

Tags: sql-server-2005, powershell

When using the sql server provider in powershell, the path I pass works fine the first time, but upon the second run it errors out on me.  It's like I have to clear the drive somehow?

Example:
sl "SQLSERVER:SQL\SERVERNAME\DEFAULT\DATABASES\DATABASENAME\Tables"
works fine the upon the first run.  The location is successfully set.  But, when I run it a 2nd time, I get this error:
Set-Location : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: The number of keys specified does not match the number of keys required to address this object. The number of keys requi
red are: Schema.Name.

I'm using quest powergui btw.  Please help, this is driving me mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're using a relative path (i.e. it doesn't start with a slash after the provider:).  So, first you've set the location relative to the default--root folder.  Then, you try to set the location again, but you're already in the "tables" folder, which doesn't have a "SQL\SERVERNAME..." folder inside it.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense Mike, but every time I try to set the path back it doesn't seem to take.  I set my location to c:\ to try to 'reset' the path, then as soon as I try to set the location back to the sql server provider location, it errors again.  Do you know of a way to 'reset' the path?  It's getting pretty dern tiresome having to restart my environment all the time to clear the path out.  Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried this, but switching between providers is just like switching between drives in DOS.  Just because you set your location (on C:) to "\", your location on D: might be \temp.  Try doing something like `set-location sqlserver:\`

Comment: ok...I tried it.  Either add a slash after the SQLServer: (so it reads sl SQLServer:\SQL\...) or, use something like "sl SQLServer:\" to change to the root between using set-location.

Comment: OMG TY!  This has been driving me absolutely bananas for months now.  Thanks you!